# NodeJs Installation issues from Git

Tags: node.js, installation

I had Node version 0.4.11 installed (it was installed a long time ago and I can't even remember how I went about installing it originally).

But I tried installing the latest version so I could start playing around with Node again and found that although the Git installation from here: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation appeared to be successful when I run `node -v` I still get `v0.4.11`?

Can I install over the top of an existing Node installation and if not how can I un-install Node so I can try running the UNIX style install from Git repository as per the Wiki page https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation demonstrates.

I've tried using https://github.com/visionmedia/n to install the latest version of Node by running its command `n 0.6.7` but although I got a `'install' finished successfully (56.705s)` it then failed to successfully remove some source files (not sure if that's an issue)...

```
... removing source
cp: /usr/local/include/node/ares.h: Permission denied
cp: /usr/local/include/node/ares_version.h: Permission denied
cp: /usr/local/include/node/c-ares/ares.h: Permission denied
cp: /usr/local/include/node/c-ares/ares_version.h: Permission denied
cp: /usr/local/include/node/config.h: Permission denied
cp: /usr/local/include/node/node.h: Permission denied
cp: /usr/local/include/node/node_buffer.h: Permission denied
cp: /usr/local/include/node/node_config.h: Permission denied
cp: /usr/local/include/node/node_object_wrap.h: Permission denied
cp: /usr/local/include/node/node_version.h: Permission denied
cp: /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/eio.h: Permission denied
cp: /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/ev.h: Permission denied
cp: /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/ngx-queue.h: Permission denied
cp: /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/tree.h: Permission denied
cp: /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-unix.h: Permission denied
cp: /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-win.h: Permission denied
cp: /usr/local/include/node/uv.h: Permission denied
cp: /usr/local/include/node/v8-debug.h: Permission denied
cp: /usr/local/include/node/v8-preparser.h: Permission denied
cp: /usr/local/include/node/v8-profiler.h: Permission denied
cp: /usr/local/include/node/v8-testing.h: Permission denied
cp: /usr/local/include/node/v8.h: Permission denied
cp: /usr/local/include/node/v8stdint.h: Permission denied
```

And then on top of that when I run `node -v` I still get `v0.4.11`?

Thanks for any help you give me on this as I'm very confused?

I've set-up an issue on Node's Issue Tracker just in case someone there could advise too: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2674

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually now fixed this issue with help from someone on twitter.

We had to remove the Node install and then re-installed it using homebrew as it seemed there were permission issues with my original Node install that prevented it from being easily removed.

I will be marking this response as the correct answer as I cannot check the previous response to confirm if it ****would**** have worked.

Answer (score 0):

your path to the node bin is not correct. You can check this by doing a

```
which node
```

The output will be the pathto node

Then do the following - 
add the path to the new node installation in your PATH env varaiable

```
export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/new/node" (add it to you bashrc)
```

also do,

```
export NODE_PATH="/path/to/new/node"
```